# Is there a way to add Facebook Like buttons to lots of products?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

I know how to add a Facebook like button for a group or page, but is it possible to add a like button to every product in a web store without having to create a group or page for each product?

#### This was originally asked on StackExchange Web Apps Private Beta [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/is-there-a-way-to-add-facebook-like-buttons-to-lots-of-products-closed)

.

Comment: If there isn't a group or page created, what is there to like?

Answer (score 2):

If each product you want users to be able to like has it's own web page (like a product detail page), then you can setup the Open Graph tags on each page, and have buttons with a custom **href** pointing to them:

```
<fb:like href="http://mystore.com/product-1"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can. Now with Facebook, you can "like" almost everything. You just have to implement it the way you'd do it for a page, or a quote. You can put it in your display loop/function.

I hope I was of any help.